# Create a custom component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, components

I'm currently learning JavaScript, HTML, and Vue.Js, and now how to work with components.
I'm taking an online course which corrects code using a bot.

The assignment is to create a component, `greet` that produces `<div>hello!</div>`when it's called using `<greet></greet>`. To complete the assignment I need to use `Vue.Component` and the `templete`-key.
I need to set the `el`-value at `new Vue`-caller so it matches `<div id="app"></div>`

This is in my HTML code so far(with script src included):

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
      <greet="greet"></greet>
    </div>
  </body>
```

This is my my Vue code so far

```
new Vue({ el: '#app' })
Vue.component('greet', {
  data() {
    return {
      greet
    }
  },
  template: '<div>hello!</div>'
})
```

The output on the HTML page is just blank, so I don't understand what I'm missing here.

The output from the bot is:

```
file.js
    ✓ exists
    ✓ is valid JavaScript
    1) renders the correct markup
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes here.

First `<greet="greet"></greet>` doesn't work. There's something calles [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) in vue (you'll learn it in future) Change that line to `<greet></greet>`
Then you don't have to use `data()` to show hello div. Delete the `greet` from data.
Above steps might fix your fault

Answer (score 0):

When you use the syntax Vue.component() you are registering a component globally, so it can be used by any new Vue instances created afterward. So:

```
new Vue({ el: '#app' }) // this Vue instance does not contain the greet component because it does not exists yet. 
Vue.component('greet', {
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  template: '<div>hello!</div>'
})
```

Instead:

```
Vue.component('greet', {
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  template: '<div>hello!</div>'
})

new Vue({ el: '#app' }) // this Vue instance will contain the greet component because it was already created and registered.
```

Also `<greet="greet"></greet>` is not valid syntax. It should be `<greet></greet>`.

You should remove greet from data() function. it has no meaning and use.

The final code should look like:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
      <greet></greet>
    </div>
</body>


Vue.component('greet', {
  template: '<div>hello!</div>'
})

new Vue({ el: '#app' })
```